# Error: "The target principal name is incorrect" when attempting to connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a Windows 2012 Server which runs SQL Server and I connect to that SQL Server remotely over a VPN from my Windows 10 Laptop using SSMS.  Recently, I had to replace the hard drive on the laptop and I did not completely copy over all my configurations, and I am now getting the error: "The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)"

When I google around, people say to create an SPN or to run the Kerberos Configuration Manager, but I'm not using Kerberos.  Other articles mention Active Directory but I'm not using Active Directory, and my laptop is set up as a Workstation, not in a domain.

I had this working before, and I did set up a Windows Credential in my user on the laptop to connect to the SQL Server with the correct domain, username, and password.

I already tried the easy things: IP address is set up correctly in laptop hosts file, rebooted both server and desktop, password is set to not expire on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Control Panel --> Users Account --> Windows Credentials.

Make sure you have added the host name / ip address to your hosts file.

Add a new Windows Credential.  For the Internet or network adddress, use the host name that you put into your hosts file, but also append the sql server port number to the end with a colon in between (usually, this is :1433).

For the Username, prepend the username with the domain name or the workgroup.  In my case, it was a workgroup.

Finally, enter the password associated with the username.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SSMS to connect to a SQL Server instance on a different host and you're using Windows authentication, SSMS is using Kerberos to authenticate on SQL instance. That's required because SQL server needs some way to ensure that the security context of SSMS in your laptop is valid.

Please try to follow the steps described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/farukcelik/new-tool-microsoft-kerberos-configuration-manager-for-sql-server-is-ready-to-resolve-your-kerberosconnectivity-issues

If you don't want to do this, you can run SSMS in the same server where the SQL instance is installed, create SQL local accounts and use them instead of logging in with Windows Credentials.

Comment: I have Kerberos Configuration Managers installed.  If I try to connect, then I get the message: "There was an issue with accessing UserAccount information from the System, Please check logs at %AppData%\Mirosoft\KerberosConfirMgr for more information".    I found the logs and I see this error: "Error: Access of User Principal information failed System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException: The server could not be contacted. ---> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable."  Any ideas what this means?

Comment: Looks like you're not on the domain. Do you have domain account in the same server where the SQL instance is installed?
In that case what I would do is to run SSMS in your laptop but starting it with a different user, the domain account. To do that, right click on the SSMS application while you keep Shift key pressed and select 'Run as a different user' then use your domain account. If that works, you can create a shortcut.

Comment: I'm not on the domain.  In fact, my laptop is set up as a workgroup, not on the domain.  I've always been able to use a Windows Credential to connect to the domain via my local workgroup user.  I did try what you suggested about 'Run as a differnt user' and as I expected, it doesn't recognize my domain login, because I am not running in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue after specifying TLS 1.2 via ServicePointManger.SecurityProtocol within a C# console application.  Adding in TLS 1.1 (along with keeping TLS 1.2, see below) fixed my issue. My guess that some portion of the network I was within was not yet using TLS 1.2 and by originally not having a security protocol specified, the SQL Connection was able to determine its own protocol.  Once I specified TLS 1.2 to be used specifically, I began to see this error.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```